# Google Chrome does not open custom protocols

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I've been using a simple mechanism for registering a custom URL protocol on Windows 10, allowing a link in our web application to launch a local program on the client computer. For example :

> <a href="mycustomprotocol://scan/0&1608962&1&248">Launch program</a>

In regedit, the protocol is registered here :

> Ordinateur\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprotocol\shell\open\command

with a value like :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\MyExecutable.exe "%1"

It has stopped to work on Chrome 63. Nothing is shown in the dev console nor in the network tab, whereas it still works well on Firefox or Microsoft Edge for example.

If I delete my user profile in C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data, then click my custom link again, Chrome asks me if I want to launch my local program but nothing happens when I click on the "open" button.

Any though ? Is this feature now blocked by Chrome ? Can this be unblocked ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing two keys in the registry. It was okay for Edge but not for Chrome. Here are the keys to add at the level Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprotocol\ :

> Name                           Type                       Data
>
> (Default)               REG_SZ                URL:My Fancy Program
>
> URL Protocol       REG_SZ

Comment: What do you mean by "URL: My Fancy Program" ... is this just a description? Is it something that needs to be accurate?

Answer (score 1):

This Chrome bug has just been fixed:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=788431

If you don't want to wait for the fix to be deployed, this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/7jblpz/chrome_keeps_asking_if_i_want_to_open_magnet/) on Reddit gives a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

We are also facing the same of Custom Protocol in **Chrome 63**.

The protocol is registered here :

`Ordinateur\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprotocol\shell\open\command`

with a value like :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram\MyExecutable.exe "%1"

Also we have both the registry entries under Computer`\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mycustomprotocol\`

```
Name               Type                  Data
(Default)          REG_SZ                URL:My Fancy Program
URL Protocol       REG_SZ
```

Browser opens the popup to allow user to launch client application. Client application launches. But always allow option is not getting save. Browser always opening popup to launch the client application